# Superfish menu inline for responsive design

Tags: wordpress, drop-down-menu, menu, responsive-design, superfish

Im having problems with superfish menu displaying inline with "responsive design" I would like to have all superfish menu links displayed inline but im having problems that superfish for submenu override all styling that i tried and always display dropdown.

Anyone know how can i disable superfish animated dropdown on mouse hover when im browsing with less than 700 px device and display all elements inline-block of superfish menu elements, submenu and submenu elements.

Current code from website is too messy so i uploaded it here http://pastebin.com/mwPjVEPX
This is directly from site.

For first ul li elements i added display:inline-block and it works but in submenu elements, first javascript from superfish add element style display:none and visibility:hidden, and when i try to add display:inline-block to override it on first hover it went back to display none.

And here is css of superfish menu http://pastebin.com/vmYkGVx4

Answer (score 0):

First of all you didn't specifically mention your code here or any link. But as i guess, all the properties you specifies to a parent, they automatically appends to its child element.
So, If you give `display: inline;` then its all children will get it and behave as if they are inline. So It is better to go `display: inline-block;`. In this case this element will behave as an inline element but itself showing as a block level element. And child will never be inline .

Comment: Yes i used display:inline-block, but it only works on parent element. On submenu elements javascript from superfish automatically add display:none and visibility:hiden and display:inline-block dont work for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Despite your CSS, the Superfish JavaScript continues to run at small screen sizes. JavaScript hides and reveals things by attaching an inline `style` attributes to alter the CSS `display` property. Inline styles will always trump CSS from any other source unless you add the `!important` keyword like so: `display: inline-block !important`. That will be worth trying. However, as the JavaScript will still be trying to act on the elements, you *may* still find other weird behaviour arising. Please let us know how you go.

Comment: Yes i know that javascript still run on small screen sizes and adding it's property to submenu. The !important is working only on first page load, as soon as i stop on menu and remove it javascript override !important settings from css again. I will try do to different approach and see how i can make it to not load superfish on small screen, that way i would have pure css menu which will be i hope easier to customize.

Answer (score 0):

Well at the end i ended up using mobilemenu . It's javascript code that on selected width hide superfish menu and display dropdown select box. From all searches it's most reasonable to use. There are some developments on superfish menu to support touch devices but still it's not supported for "responsive design" although there are posts on various blogs talking that next step is to make it responsive, untill than i used this addon https://github.com/mattkersley/Responsive-Menu